# iOS UIViewController,why "self" become to "wild pointer" in viewDidUnload？

Tags: ios, uitableview, pointers, viewdidunload

my code snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.statusView = nil;
    self.tableView = nil;
    self.noDataView = nil;
}
```

In a rare situation, my app crashed in line `self.noDataView = nil;`. When I debug by `po self`, it seemed that it's pointing something other than current controller. What is possible reason?

PS:`self.tableView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` is set to `self` in `init` method. Does that have any relation to this?

Comment: Don't implement viewDidUnload to nil out views... Apple has moved away from this method anyway.

Comment: These views are not created by NIB, are created by code in `init` or `loadView` method, then are added to `self.view` as subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `[super viewDidUnload]` should be used as the last statement. However, that won't fix your error, probably.

The reason for your problem is quite simple. Your controller is overreleased somewhere. Do you have zombie detection enabled? The code where the application crashes is usually irrelevant because the problem happened earlier.

Comment: I know the root reason is that `controller` is over released, but I can't find where this happened, because I used **ARC**. \r\nAnd I also understand `dangling point` won't bring destruction immediately, however I test many times and the debugger hang at the same code line position every time, the possibility of coincidence is little, I think. It is strange that not

Comment: It is strange that not every time App crash, it's rare, but   sometimes it continuity crash and hang at same line `self.noDataView = nil;`, the line ahead of this used `self` too, but no error.

Comment: @naiyi1984 That's why I am telling you the problem is not in this code at all. The controller is already released and you get the crash when you try to overwrite memory that no longer belongs to you. Sometimes overwriting memory doesn't crash and sometimes it does. However, the problem is that your controller is overreleased.

Comment: Forget debugger and use instruments.

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillUnload` is deprecated now, you can't count on it anymore, any question about it will lead you to the below references.

**From Apple:**

> In iOS 6, the viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods of
>   UIViewController are now deprecated. If you were using these methods
>   to release data, use the didReceiveMemoryWarning method instead. You
>   can also use this method to release references to the view
>   controller’s view if it is not being used. You would need to test that
>   the view is not in a window before doing this.

**And Quote WWDC 2012:**

> The method viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload. We're not going to call
>   them anymore. I mean, there's kind of a cost-benifit equation and
>   analysis that we went through. In the early days, there was a real
>   performance need for us to ensure that on memory warnings we unloaded
>   views. There was all kinds of graphics and backing stores and so forth
>   that would also get unloaded. We now unload those independently of the
>   view, so it isn't that big of a deal for us for those to be unloaded,
>   and there were so many bugs where there would be pointers into.

**Edit**:
For your problem in iOS 5.1, `viewDidUnload` is used to release anything you have made when the view was created, so unless you are creating or retaining objects it in `viewDidLoad` or your `nib`, you may not release them in `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: I know this method was deprecated from iOS6, but I get this crash in **iOS 5.1.1** which I think it should be still valid.

Comment: Are you initializing self.noDataView in `init` or `viewDidLoad`? and is it a `outelt`?

Comment: Yes.I'm sure `self.noDataView` is correctly initialized. It is not a `outlet`.

Comment: No I am asking where do you initialize it? check my edit, if you are not initialize it in `viewDIdLoad` then don't release it in `viewDidUnload`, do it in `dealloc`.

Comment: Oh,I init all these three view in `loadView` method, just after `[super loadView];`

Comment: From the apples doc: `If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller, you must not override this method.` so if you did put them in `viewDidLoad` instead, and I recommend to get `self.noDataView = nil;` out of viewDidUnload.